# What do the Snake Idols in Binded form Indicate?

Tags: temple, worship, idols

In many Hindu Temples we can see Snake Idol which has two Snakes, bound to each other like a DNA.

**QUESTION :**

- What does this form of two snakes indicate and why do we worship it ?

Below is a picture for reference:

[image]

Comment: these are the ida and pingala, the two nerve currents that run from the brain down the spinal column.

Comment: How to worship it to awaken Kundalini.. Y is sushumna not represented?

Comment: Incredible. The Ida/Pingala meaning is amazing 