# Is nagas in temple related to Kundalini?

Tags: temple, mantras, worship, naga

Does naga in temples represent kundalini? 
If yes how can it be used for ones spiritual enhancenent? 
What are the mantras one can use to worship it?

Comment: Actually the two nagas in opposite sides represents Kundalini shakti... but this is much deeper on Kundalini than what we think. Kundalini itself is deeper subject!

Comment: This is already asked: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17946/what-does-the-snake-idols-in-binded-form-indicate

Comment: Thanks but there also there is no answer to my question.

Comment: @TheRise2arun If the question is already present, then no need to ask same question again. It's better to check with existing question. If it has no answer, edit it/flag it to dump on main site page in order to get the attention again.